# Thymeleaf modelvariables not recognized correctly by Intellij when using fragments

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, thymeleaf

I am trying to work with Spring-Boot and want to use Thymeleaf as my template-engine. For some reason when I want to use model variables in my thymeleaf-fragments, then code completion does not work correctly. For example, I am defining one of my fragments like so:

```
<div th:fragment="destThemeDiv(adminViewDTO)">
```

When I now want to use the adminViewDTO in some expression it works but IntelliJ doesn't recognize the members of adminViewDTO when I want to access them and underlines them in red. For example when I do this:

```
<th:block th:each="someObject: ${adminViewDTO.someObjects}">
```

Then someObjects is underlined read, which seems obvious since IntelliJ cannot infer the type parameter on its own, however even if I provide a type hint on the top of my fragment it still does not work correctly:

```
<!--@thymesVar id="adminViewDTO" type="test.view.AdminViewDTO"-->
```

Is there any way to make this work correctly? I didn't really find anyone else who was complaining about this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I kind of think I figured it out. When I put the type-hint directly above the block where I use the expression instead of inserting it at the top of the page, then it works.

Like so:

```
<!--@thymesVar id="adminViewDTO" type="test.view.AdminViewDTO"-->
<th:block th:each="someObject : ${adminViewDTO.someObjects}">
  <!--When using someObject in expression here, it will be recognized-->
</th:block>
```