# IntelliJ doesn't autocomplete (spring) Thymeleaf in fragments files

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-thymeleaf

As of IntelliJ 2023.2 the issue [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-207277) has not been resolved for 5 years and I only managed to find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54246291/thymeleaf-modelvariables-not-recognized-correctly-by-intellij-when-using-fragmen) question, but it uses an (old?) answer that has issues itself ([eg](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-304490/ThymeLeaf-thymesVar-type-annotation-not-resolved-when-at-top-of-template)).

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/events")
class EventsController(val eventsService: EventService) {
    @RequestMapping
    fun getEventsView(model: Model): String {
        val events: List<Event> = this.blogService.findAll()
        model.addAttribute("events", events)
        model.addAttribute("bodyContent", "pages/events")
        return "master-template"
    }
}
```

where in `master-template.html` I have a `<th:block th:replace="${bodyContent}"></th:block>`. Although the issue persists even when `${bodyContent}` is substituded by hand with `pages/events`.

For the code above, IntelliJ will autocomplete for `events` and `bodyContent` in the `master-template.html` file, but it won't autocomplete in the `pages/events.html` file.

IntelliJ however offers:
[image: suggestion: 'Declare external variable in comment annotation']
when you try to use the variables, but it doesn't work still (unrelated IntelliJ problem?, because it properly places the @thymesVar comment).

I'm posting this question to ask if there is a proper way to make autocomplete work in the fragment file from outside of the file?

Comment: A little later with the workarounds, autocomplete works with `event` properties for `event` from the `events` list, but the properties still get a `Cannot resolve 'property_name'` warning.

Answer (score 0):

Although not a nice solution, adding this line to the controller is a valid and short workaround:

`if(false) return "pages/events"`

Additionally the problem with [image: suggestion: 'Declare external variable in comment annotation'] disappears when I wrap the entire fragment file with `<th:block xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"><\th:block>` (but this is unwanted when you don't use explicit th:fragment, and instead the fragment is the entire file with multiple html tags in sequence. another reason is it gets really messy if the tag containing `xmlns` is not first in the file). It seems like everything thymeleaf related works without `xmlns` except for the `@thymesVar` comment.